# How often per Day can the Living Missile Attack power be used?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The Effect line of the [Living Missile](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13308) power card reads:

> While the target is immobilized or slowed by this power, you can use the Living Missile Attack power once per round.

The Requirement line of Living Missile Attack's card says:

> The power Living Missile must be active in order to use this power. This power may be used once per round.

This seems to imply that the Living Missile Attack power may be used once per round, indefinitely, until the primary target of Living Missile successfully saves against the Immobilized or Slowed condition.

However, the Living Missile Attack power card is marked as a Daily power.

Which of these frequency of use specifications apply?  Is this a valid case of "specific overrides general", where the "once per round" for Living Missile Attack replaces the "once per day" property of Daily powers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The Living Missile power may be used once per day.**

Living Missile Attack, effectively a secondary attack of Living Missile, may be used until the target saves out of the slowed or immobilized effects of Living Missile.

The frequency of use is clearly spelled out:

[Living missile](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13308) notes:

> Hit: The target is immobilized (save ends).
>
> Miss: The target is slowed (save ends).
>
> Effect: While the target is immobilized or slowed by this power, you can use the Living Missile Attack power once per round.

Thus, until the target saves or 5 minutes have passed (duration of an encounter), suggested by the [stance](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=84) definition:

> A stance power lasts until the end of the encounter, for 5 minutes, or until you use another stance power.

There are no contradictions here. While the power is a daily, the attached power has its uses very clearly spelled out, and therefore we obey them:

> Requirement: The power Living Missile must be active in order to use this power. This power may be used once per round.

Comment: Irrelevant correction - there is no 5 minute limit to (save ends) duration.  On the off chance that you can keep someone from saving for 5 minutes, and yet not kill him, you can take as long as you want.  (From the Rules Compendium)

Comment: Really? Neat... I don't suppose that has a corresponding reference on DDI?

Comment: @Pat - Page reference from the RC, please?

Comment: @Iszi, sorry D&D stuff is crated in the garage while relatives are here for the holidays.  It'll be a week before I can answer.

Comment: @Iszi - or perhaps closer to 3 weeks!  Rules Compendium pg226-7 covers durations

Comment: @Brian I don't see anything in the DDI about clarifying durations, sorry